# Error in thymeleaf templetEngine processing while trying to generate PDF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to generate PDF from thymeleaf templet.But I am getting  error while templateEngine.process() method executes.The error is as below :

**org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Resource resolution by ServletContext with org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.ServletContextResourceResolver can only be performed when context implements org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext**

Please help.Thanks in advance.

**Controller Method**

```
  @Autowired
  TemplateEngine templateEngine;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/print-pdf",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> view() throws IOException {

        UserDto userDto = userService.findUserById(100689);

        ByteArrayInputStream bis=null;
        try {
            bis = pdfGenerator.createAndViewPdf("html_to_print",userDto);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=user.pdf");

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(bis));

    }
```

**PDF service method**

```
public ByteArrayInputStream createAndViewPdf(String templateName, UserDto userDto) throws Exception {

        ByteOutputStream os = new ByteOutputStream();
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        Context ctx = new Context();
        ctx.setVariable("userDto",userDto);


        String processedHtml = templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);

        renderer.setDocumentFromString(processedHtml);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);

        byte[] pdfAsBytes = os.getBytes();
        os.close();


        return new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfAsBytes);
    }
```

**XML based templetEngine configuration**

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="dialects">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.dialect.SpringStandardDialect" />
            </set>
        </property>
        <property name="templateResolvers">
            <set>

                <bean
                      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/user/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
                    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
                    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
                    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
                </bean>

            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

**Dependency added in pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
      <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
      <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
      <version>9.1.16</version>
  </dependency>

Folder structure
```

[image]

Comment: what is the value of templateName are you passing at Runtime to createAndViewPdf()?

Comment: the value is "html_to_print" which is the name of html file (html_to_print.html).I am not passing the .html extension as I previously declared prefix and suffix inside templetResolver

Comment: can you add your resources structure?it can help

Comment: I have edited the post.Check the structure @slimane

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with the PDF generation.  In fact, you should probably refactor the code that creates the HTML into a separate method and see whether you get the same error without calling the PDF code.